# jmeter load testing 403 forbidden

Tags: jmeter

I am running a load test against our application (250 threads with 10 loops) and it never succeeds. error rate dominates with > 95% every run and have no clue what is going wrong. error is 403 forbidden across both GET and POST requests I have cookie manager with Hc4Cookiehandler implementation and policy is set to standard also got cache manager added in my test plan.

I have tweaked the JMeter settings as suggested in other forums, still no luck.

```
httpclient4.retrycount=1

http.connection.stalecheckBoolean=true

https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

the interesting part is that certain requests are passing through fine and result 200 success. wondering if something is wrong with the jmeter configuration which is letting major requests to fail.

sample result:

```
summary =  24000 in 00:00:34 =  702.9/s Avg:   122 Min:     5 Max:  5347 Err: 23795 (99.15%)

403:

1556876389725,12,GET-/visitor/captureJobSearch.do,403,Forbidden,DT-ChildCare 1-45,text,false,Test failed: message expected to contain /OK/,519,945,100,100,11,0,4

200:

1556876387936,1564,GET-/visitor/captureSearchBar.do,200,OK,DT-ChildCare 1-1,text,true,,21616,473,100,100,1561,0,768
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing on *CSRF tokens*, try implementing the same on `HTTP Header Manager` and `HTTP Cookie Manager`

Comment: yes, i have added referrer and origin to be same as our domain which should take care of handling csrf check. still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 forbidden is mainly arise due to authentication failure . Try passing the authentication values(all values including JWT token or cookie details) hard corded in cookie manager. And keep the cookie manager in under thread group or just above the requests with Http Header manager.

Comment: requests being exercised are of visitor pages and doesnt require any authentication or authorization. weird thing is that, 3-4% of requests succeed on every run. if something is wrong with the config, wouldnt all the requests fail?

Comment: Try contacting the person who have access to the servers. If there is a load balancer in between or even if the request goes directly to the server, there would be some restrictions in load balancer or servers not to accept concurrent or sequential request from same ip. If so your requests beyond a certain limit will throw back with 401 or 403. What you can do is to add an exception in the server for your ip. Or else try using ip spoofing with jmeter

Comment: yes, it was a restriction put up on the servers. waf had rate limit set and bypassing the IP's helped. thanks!

Comment: Hi @Vijay , I also have the same issue. I want to know how did you by pass the Ip's can you please explain?